# Using class EmbeddedChannel test codec : invoking writeOutbound() method then invoking readOutbound()

Tags: java, netty

When I use class `EmbeddedChannel` to test the correctness of `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` and `LengthFieldPrepender` in custom protocol with `ProtoBuf`，I expect to get all data by encoding . Firstly, I invoke the method `ch.writeOutbound()` to add my message object. Second , I invoke the method `ch.readOutbound()` to get the ByteBuf. I expect get the ByteBuf that combines the length field ByteBuf and the message ByteBuf. But I only get ByteBuf wrapping the length field which is `PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 4, cap: 4)`. That confuses me. Then I debug the program. I can understand the principle about polling from `outmessage`. So I get the length field ByteBuf firstly. Why designing in this way? Can I get all the data by encoding. The following is my test code.

```
@test
public void testAlarmProto(){

    AlarmProto.Alarm.Builder builder = AlarmProto.Alarm.newBuilder();

    builder.setCommunity("Quene Home");
    builder.setBuildingId(31);
    builder.setBuildingPart("B");
    builder.setCellId(1);
    builder.setRoomId(204);
    builder.setAlarmCategory("Fire");
    builder.setAttachment("Current time");

    MessageProto.MessageBase.Body.Builder body = MessageProto.MessageBase.Body.newBuilder();
    body.setContext(builder.build());

    MessageProto.MessageBase.Header.Builder header =MessageProto.MessageBase.Header.newBuilder();
    header.setType(MessageProto.MessageBase.MessageType.SERVICE_REQ);

    MessageProto.MessageBase.Builder message = MessageProto.MessageBase.newBuilder();
    message.setHeader(header.build());
    message.setBody(body.build());

   //create EmbeddedChannel
    EmbeddedChannel ch = new EmbeddedChannel();

    ch.pipeline().addLast("frameDecoder",new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(1048576,0,4,0,4));
   // ch.pipeline().addLast("frameDecoder",new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());
    ch.pipeline().addLast("decoder",new ProtobufDecoder(MessageProto.MessageBase.getDefaultInstance()));
    ch.pipeline().addLast("frameEncoder",new LengthFieldPrepender(4));

  //  ch.pipeline().addLast("frameEncoder",new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());
    ch.pipeline().addLast("encoder",new ProtobufEncoder());

   //write outbound data to ch
    ch.writeOutbound(message.build());

   //get data from ch but only the 
    ByteBuf byteBuf = ch.readOutbound();

    ch.writeInbound(byteBuf);
    ch.finish();
    MessageProto.MessageBase messageBase = ch.readInbound();

    System.out.println(messageBase.getHeader().getType().getNumber());
    System.out.println(messageBase.getBody().getContext().getBuildingPart());

}
```

Comment: Note that certain encoders call `write` multiple times, and thus you have to call `ch.readOutbound()` to get all the data

Comment: Can I get a detailed explanation.Thanks very much.